# How to correctly insert blob data into table

Tags: qt, sqlite

I try to write an array of data in a table, but I get the error "Parameter count mismatch"

```cpp
auto query = new QSqlQuery(db);


request = QString("INSERT INTO items(id, type, data) VALUES"
                          "('%0', '%1', :bytes)").
                            arg(id).
                            arg(static_cast<int>(type));

// request: INSERT INTO items(id, type, data) VALUES('0', '512', :bytes)
query->prepare(request)); // ok
query->bindValue(":bytes", bytes); // bytes is qbytearray with data
query->exec(request) // error  Parameter count mismatch
```

- OS: ubuntu 18.04
- Qt: 5.12.3, 5.9.7

  How to write data correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I gave my original request to the function parameters, it replaced the one on which the "bindValue" function was executed.

#### Need to replace

```cpp
query->exec(request);
```

#### by

```cpp
query->exec();
```